# Good coding style to do case-select in XSLT

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xslt

I want to have a page display A,B,C,D depending on the return value from XML value (1,2,3,4). My approaches are by javascript or XSLT:choose. I want to know which way is better, and why? Can I do this case-select in .cs code (good or bad)? Should I javascript code in XSLT? Can the community please advise? Thanks.

Below are the code.

**Javascript way (this one works):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:js="urn:custom-javascript">
  <xsl:template match="page">

    <msxsl:script language="JavaScript" implements-prefix="js">
      <![CDATA[
        function translateSkillLevel(level)
        {
          switch (level)
          {
            case 0: return "Level 1";
            case 1: return "Level 2";
            case 2: return "Level 3";
          }
        return "unknown";
        }
        ]]>
    </msxsl:script>

    <div id="skill">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Level</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="/page/Skill">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <!-- difference here -->
              <script type="text/javascript">
                document.write(translateSkillLevel(<xsl:value-of select="@level"/>));
              </script>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Javascript way (this one doesn't work, getting undefined js tag):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:js="urn:custom-javascript">
  <xsl:template match="page">

    <msxsl:script language="JavaScript" implements-prefix="js">
      <![CDATA[
        function translateSkillLevel(level)
        {
          switch (level)
          {
            case 0: return "Level 1";
            case 1: return "Level 2";
            case 2: return "Level 3";
          }
        return "unknown";
        }
        ]]>
    </msxsl:script>

    <div id="skill">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Level</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="/page/Skill">
          <tr>
            <td>
               <!-- difference here -->
               <xsl:value-of select="js:translateSkillLevel(string(@level))"/>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT way:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="page">
    <div id="skill">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Level</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="/page/Skill">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@level = 0">
                  Level 1
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@level = 1">
                  Level 2
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@level = 2">
                  Level 3
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  unknown
                </xsl:otherwisexsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT:
Also, I have some inline javascript functions for form submit.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();return false;"/>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an XSLT solution that is most customizable, flexible and extensible. At the same time it is so simple that it doesn't contain even a single selection logic instruction. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the XSLT way would be something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="page">
        <div id="skill">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Level</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </table>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Skill">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@level"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@level">Unknown</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@level[3>.]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Level ',.+1)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<page>
    <Skill level="1"/>
    <Skill level="4"/>
</page>
```

Output:

```
<div id="skill">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Level</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Level 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unknown</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Second: You first stylesheet doesn't "work" as it is, unless you define into some HTML `SCRIPT` element the `translateSkillLevel` javascript function (or better, an external `LINK`).

Third: Your second stylesheet could "work", but **inline extension functions implementations are not the standard XSLT extension mechanism**. That's why you are using a **not standard extension element** making your stylesheet not portable between XSLT processors.

Answer (score 3):

Out of these two, I would definitely go for the XSLT way. There's no need to invoke an entire script engine for just this.

Comment: What if my code has button onclick="javascript:document.forms[0].submit();". Maybe the script engine will be invoked only when clicking button. However, my point is I am using javascript somewhere else in my code.

Comment: @Stan: Having JavaScript in your output is completely unrelated. (By the way, never ever use "`javascript:`" anywhere - it's a sign of you doing something wrong)

Comment: +1 For script engine reference. Remember that for **every** extension function invocation the script engine will be instantiated

Answer (score 1):

No extension functions are necessary, XSLT is powerful and flexible enough.

**The XSLT implementation I would recommend is this** (largely customizable, flexible and extensible):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">

 <my:skills>
  <s v="0" d="1"/>
  <s v="1" d="2"/>
  <s v="2" d="3"/>
  <other>unknown</other>
 </my:skills>

 <xsl:variable name="vSkills" select=
  "document('')/*/my:skills/*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vUnknown" select=
  "document('')/*/my:skills/other"/>

 <xsl:template match="page">
    <div id="skill">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Level</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Skill/@level"/>
        </table>
    </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@level">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:variable name="vSkill" select=
      "$vSkills[@v=current()]/@d"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$vSkill|$vUnknown[not($vSkill)]"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when the above transformation is applied to the following XML document**:

```
<page>
    <Skill level="1"/>
    <Skill level="4"/>
</page>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<div id="skill">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Level</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>unknown</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Do note**:

1. **All the rules for translating a current skill value to a display value are specified as data**.
2. **The decision data can be in a separate document** so that complete parameterization is achieved.
3. **We do not rely on an accidental dependency** ( such as dispValue = value +1) -- any relation b/n the current value and the display value can be expressed.
4. **There is absolutely no conditional logic in the XSLT code**!

Comment: @Dimtre: +1 For the mapping data example. My answer mostly has the intention to highlight the pattern matching approach and to go against not standard extension model... I think that you should consider to answer that also.